# Batch - Adding Users to Multiple Groups Through For Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

In my last question I discussed how I was working on a new mass user creation script and am now at approximately 95 lines. I received a solution to that question and tried to implement that into a different section of the code. Right now I am trying to add users from an Excel document to multiple groups using a for loop nested in the main for loop that creates the users, mail enables them etc.

Right now this is what I have:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=37 tokens=* delims=," %%a in (Settings.ini) do (
set Groups=%%a
)


for /f "skip=1 Tokens=1,2,3 Delims=," %%a in (C:\UserList.csv) do (
set User=%%a
set "GroupsAdd=net group %groups:,= /add !User! && net group %"
!GroupsAdd! /add %%a
)
```

As you can see, the script skips thirty-seven lines in the Settings file until it reaches the desired line and sets the groups variable to that line. The next for loop tries to add the user to the specified groups defined in the Settings file, e.g. Students, StudentProxy, Year12 etc.

That is where the code fails, it delivers me to the help menu for net group, I have experimented with other things such as not using delayed expansion and that delivered an error stating:

```
/Add is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**TL;DR I need to create a function that will add users in an Excel file to specified groups in a Settings file using net group however the way I am doing it now continually fails and I need help.**

Comment: GroupsAdd is probably empty. What is the SET "GroupsAdd... line supposed to do?

Comment: GroupsAdd is not empty. The line in the settings file contains groups and when I set echo to off it writes the correct user groups. GroupsAdd is supposed to create a command: net group GROUPNAME /add USERNAME and this changes each time the group changes - i.e. it would do this three times if I had defined three groups.

Comment: You're trying to change all occurrences of a comma in the `GroupsAdd` variable with `/add !User! && net group`. I can give you two reasons this won't work: 1. There won't be any commas in `GroupsAdd` because a delimiter for the `for` loop that sets it is a comma. 2. It contains `&&` in it, which needs to be escaped otherwise it will fail. I'm assuming you don't want to do that...?

Comment: Even without setting the delim to a comma it still won't work. Also && should work because the set function is surrounded by quotes. Note that this works perfectly if the script doesn't have to read from the Excel file. ETA: With the comma as the delimeter it will still set Groups to the whole string, not separated by commas.

Comment: When is it reading from an Excel file? I'm guessing it's somewhere in previous code. I'm not quite sure it can read from an Excel file, have you done it before?

Comment: By Excel file I meant a CSV - comma delimited, it can read that as you can set the delim to a comma. It's reading from an Excel file in the second part of the script - the second for loop.

Comment: How have you tried to debug it (PS, if you don't add something like `@prof` then I won't know you replied). What is the value of `GroupsAdd` at certain intervals? I think rene is on to something, the only reason I can think of why that error message would be coming up is because `GroupsAdd` is empty.

Comment: @ProfPickle This is the output when echo is off: set "GroupsAdd=net group Test /add !un! && net group Test2 /add !un! && net group Test3" Then it executes the GroupsAdd as well as /add !un! after the end as it wasn't defined previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that `!`s are used for *delayed* expansion. That means that an expression delimited with `!`s is supposed to expand at a later time than the expression delimited with `%`s.

In your present code, a `!`-delimited expression is put inside a `%`-delimited one. This way the former is never given a chance to expand:

- The `%` expansion takes place earlier and at that particular time when it does, `!`s are not supposed to be processed and recognised as special symbols. So, the `/add !User! && net group %` bit is inserted literally, without expanding the `!User!`.
- Later, when you expand the entire `GroupsAdd` thing, the `!`s inside it do not work again, because the time for expanding those is precisely when `GroupsAdd` is being expanded, not *afterwards*. In other words, `!`s aren't expanded recursively.

I can see two options here:

1. Put the `!GroupsAdd! /add %%a` into a subroutine, replacing `!`s with `%`s and `%%a` with `%User%`:

   ```
   ...
   for /f "skip=1 Tokens=1,2,3 Delims=," %%a in (C:\UserList.csv) do (
   set User=%%a
   set "GroupsAdd=net group %groups:,= /add !User! && net group %"
   call :GroupsAdd
   )
   goto :EOF
   :GroupsAdd
   %GroupsAdd% /add %User%
   ```
2. Get rid of the `User` variable and, in the `set GroupsAdd` command, replace the `!User!` with `%%a`, as well as the `%` expansion with the `!` one:

   ```
   ...
   for /f "skip=1 Tokens=1,2,3 Delims=," %%a in (C:\UserList.csv) do (
   set "GroupsAdd=net group !groups:,= /add %%a && net group !"
   !GroupsAdd! /add %%a
   )
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked perfectly however I couldn't get the second option working. Thanks for your answer.